# canvas getImageData function throws exception in chrome

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

This snippet is based on **CANVAS**, it does convert image to grey scale and then apply some color overlay on image,it does proper work on **Mozilla Firefox** but not in chrome. In chrome it will give me an error message.

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on
>   'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by
>   cross-origin data.

[image]

Kindly provide me some solution,

Thanks in advance.

```js
  <script>
    function tintImage(imgElement, tintColor) {
      // create hidden canvas (using image dimensions)
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.width = imgElement.offsetWidth;
      canvas.height = imgElement.offsetHeight;

      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(imgElement, 0, 0);
      var map = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
      var imdata = map.data;

      // convert image to grayscale
      var r, g, b, avg;
      for (var p = 0, len = imdata.length; p < len; p += 4) {
        r = imdata[p];
        g = imdata[p + 1];
        b = imdata[p + 2];

        avg = Math.floor((r + g + b) / 3);

        imdata[p] = imdata[p + 1] = imdata[p + 2] = avg;
      }

      ctx.putImageData(map, 0, 0);

      // overlay filled rectangle using lighter composition
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "overlay";
      ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
      ctx.fillStyle = tintColor;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      // replace image source with canvas data
      imgElement.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    }



    /// some buttons for testing the demo



    var redBtt = document.createElement("button");
    redBtt.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Red"));
    redBtt.onclick = function() {
      tintImage(
        document.getElementById('myImage'),
        "#d60000"
      );
    }
    document.body.appendChild(redBtt);


    var grnBtt = document.createElement("button");
    grnBtt.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Green"));
    grnBtt.onclick = function() {
      tintImage(
        document.getElementById('myImage'),
        "#000000"
      );
    }
    document.body.appendChild(grnBtt);


    var bluBtt = document.createElement("button");
    bluBtt.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Blue"));
    bluBtt.onclick = function() {
      tintImage(
        document.getElementById('myImage'),
        "#050c8c"
      );
    }
    document.body.appendChild(bluBtt);

    </script>
```

```html
<img id='myImage' src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-gjxoCu8Fu3c/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/Uji17DdykF4/s900-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg" />

<br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of an [Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issue than, `getImageData` function.

To resolve the issue, you need to ...

**ꜰɪʀꜱᴛ**

Set `crossorigin` attribute for the image element, like so ...

```
<img crossorigin="anonymous" src="www.example.com/myImage.png">
```

**ꜱᴇᴄᴏɴᴅ**

Host the image on your local server or a website that supports cross origin resource sharing       *(ie. imgur.com)*

Comment: another possibility: you might be browsing the files from local file system, and that is causing the issue on chrome. you may perhaps create a server using [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

Comment: Thanks! @gaand, but whenever i have set image crossorigin="anonymous". it will disappear.

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake, after reading your answer carefully, my code is run perfectly, thank @gaand

Comment: yup! sure @gaand